# Laravel Users follow

Tags: php, laravel

I have this error

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'id' in field list is ambiguous (SQL: select id, followers.user_id as pivot_user_id, followers.follows_id as pivot_follows_id, followers.created_at as pivot_created_at, followers.updated_at as pivot_updated_at from users inner join followers on users.id = followers.follows_id where followers.user_id = 1 and follows_id = 2 limit 1)
>
> (View: /Users/harshitsingh/Documents/logos/resources/views/users/index.blade.php)
> and this is my UsersController

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\User;
use Image;
use Auth;
use Profile;
use App\Post;
use App\Notifications\UserFollowed;

class UsersController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $users = User::where('id', '!=', auth()->user()->id)->get();
        return view('users.index', compact('users'));
    }

    public function profile(){
        return view('profile');
    }


    public function update_avatar(Request $request){

            // Handle the user upload of avatar
        if($request->hasFile('avatar')){
            $avatar = $request->file('avatar');
            $filename = time() . '.' . $avatar->getClientOriginalExtension();
            Image::make($avatar)
            ->resize(300, 300)
            ->save( public_path('/uploads/avatars/' . $filename ) 
        );

            $user = Auth::user();
            $user->avatar = $filename;
            $user->save();
        }

        return redirect('/');

    }

    public function follow(User $user)
    {
        $follower = auth()->user();
        if ($follower->id == $user->id) {
            return back()->withError("You can't follow yourself");
        }
        if(!$follower->isFollowing($user->id)) {
            $follower->follow($user->id);

            // sending a notification
            $user->notify(new UserFollowed($follower));

            return back()->withSuccess("You are now friends with {$user->name}");
        }
        return back()->withError("You are already following {$user->name}");
    }

    public function unfollow(User $user)
    {
        $follower = auth()->user();
        if($follower->isFollowing($user->id)) {
            $follower->unfollow($user->id);
            return back()->withSuccess("You are no longer friends with {$user->name}");
        }
        return back()->withError("You are not following {$user->name}");
    }

    public function notifications()
    {
        return auth()->user()->unreadNotifications()->limit(5)->get()->toArray();
    }


    public function show(Post $post, $id)
    {
        $user = User::findOrFail($id);
        return view('user.profile', compact('user'));
    }
}
```

I am trying user to user relationship
this is User Model
`

```
 public function followers() 
        {
            return $this->belongsToMany(self::class, 'followers', 'follows_id', 'user_id')
                        ->withTimestamps();
        }
    
        public function follows() 
        {
            return $this->belongsToMany(self::class, 'followers', 'user_id', 'follows_id')
                        ->withTimestamps();
        }
    
        public function follow($userId) 
        {
            $this->follows()->attach($userId);
            return $this;
        }
    
        public function unfollow($userId)
        {
            $this->follows()->detach($userId);
            return $this;
        }
    
        public function isFollowing($userId) 
        {
            return (boolean) $this->follows()->where('follows_id', $userId)->first(['id']);
        }
```

`

Comment: two table same column name. use select table_name.column_name

Comment: @Bugfixer where?

Comment: select **id**, followers.user_id as pivot_user_id, followers.follows_id as pivot_follows_id, followers.created_at as pivot_created_at, followers.updated_at as pivot_updated_at from users inner join followers on users.id = followers.follows_id where followers.user_id = 1 and follows_id = 2 limit 1

check the bold part this id is available in both tables of join.

Comment: add usermodel code in question.

Comment: Can you tell exactly which line is causing the error?

Comment: in User.php last one
`
return (boolean) $this->follows()->where('follows_id', $userId)->first(['id']);
`

Comment: Try changing that line's `->first(['id'])` to  `->first()`.

Comment: yeah that worked but having another error  Argument 1 passed to App\Notifications\UserFollowed::__construct() must be an instance of App\Notifications\User, instance of App\User given, called in /Users/harshitsingh/Documents/logos/app/Http/Controllers/UsersController.php on line 56

Comment: Have you used the `Notifiable` traits in your user model?
https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/notifications#using-the-notifiable-trait

Comment: @SteD         yeah I used that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to learn how to read the error message.

`SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'id' in field list is ambiguous`

This message tells you that there's 2 or more `id` field, which SQL doesn't know which one to `SELECT`. From your `UserController` code, the code doesn't seem to be in there, chances are you need to look at your `User` model.

You will have to update

`SELECT id ...`

to

`SELECT users.id ...`

Answer (score 0):

I know this is kinda late but in the user model u can change this code

```
public function isFollowing($userId) 
{
   return (boolean) $this->follows()->where('follows_id', $userId)->first(['id']);
}
```

to

```
public function isFollowing($userId)
{
    return !is_null($this->follows()->where('follow_id', $userId)->first());
}
```

and then it should all work!